# A function that accept a pid and returns its mode

Tags: process, signals, system-calls

I'm looking for a C function that accepts a pgid (process group ID) and returns whether this process group runs or stops.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach would be to use `waitpid()` with the `WNOHANG` option. `waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG)` waits for a child process or process group identified by `pid` to change state.

Without the `WNOHANG` option, the function will block the calling process until the process group changes state. Including the option ensures that `waitpid` will return with a value of `0` if no children have changed state yet. (The function returns `pid` if the state has changed.) You can check for different state changes such as termination, catching a stop signal, catching a resume signal, etc.

```
pid_t pid, w;
int   status;

/* A call to fork, perhaps
 * (pid is set to child's)
 */

/* Parent can check for child's termination */
w = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);

if (w == -1)
    handle_error("waitpid_error");

if (w == 0)
    printf("child still running\n");
else
    printf("child exited\n");
```

Note that if the child terminated, the call to `waitpid` reaps the child.

Comment: But the problem with this idea is that if I get a process that I don't know for sure whether it has children or not, using waitpid() and WNOHANG will terminate one of its children. 

I'm looking for a more generic solution, that will help me get an answer for every process without terminating any sub-process.

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what you want to do. `waitpid` does not affect any of the target processes in any way (unless they have terminated on their own), it just gets information about them. I've searched a little bit and you may want to look into `/proc` if you are on a Linux system and want potential alternatives.